# How to unpack a list of nested DTO objects to list of different entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a List of DTO and I need to map this DTO to two different list of entities objects. I am new to Java and Springboot. I found examples where two DTOs are mapped to one Entity object.
For example, http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Person Entity -> id, name.

Address Entity -> Street, State.

DTO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class PersonDTO {

  private int id;

  private String name;

  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  private List<Address> address;
}
```

I need to map a list of above DTO to a list of below entity objects:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

  private int id;
  private String name;

}
```

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

  private int Street;
  private String State;

}
```

How do I map a list of PersonDTO to list of Person and list of Address ?

Comment: Don’t use Lombok if possible. It does nice things in a non-nice way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.modelmapper.TypeToken` to map List

```
List<Person> persons = modelmapper.map(personDTOs,new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType());
```

And for Address list use this

```
List<Address> addresses = personDTOs.stream().map(PersonDTO::getAddress)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Did you try this solution ?